# How to properly load an instance from a DLL implementing a specific base class in C#?

Tags: c#, dll

I have a problem where I have a program that should load a plugin (DLL) from a specific directory where the DLL implements a specific base class. The problem is that my program that loads the DLL has a reference to an other DLL which the DLL being loaded also references. I will show an example of how the problem arises. This simple tests consists of 3 different solutions and 3 separate projects. **NOTE:** If I have all projects in the same solution, the problem does not arise.

**Solution 1 - Project that defines the Base class and an interface**
**AdapterBase.cs**

```
namespace AdapterLib
{
    public interface IAdapter
    {
        void PrintHello();
    }

    public abstract class AdapterBase
    {
        protected abstract IAdapter Adapter { get; }

        public void PrintHello()
        {
            Adapter.PrintHello();
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 2 - Project that defines an implementation of the base class**
**MyAdapter.cs**

```
namespace MyAdapter
{
    public class MyAdapter : AdapterBase
    {
        private IAdapter adapter;

        protected override IAdapter Adapter
        {
            get { return adapter ?? (adapter = new ImplementedTestClass()); }
        }
    }

    public class ImplementedTestClass : IAdapter
    {
        public void PrintHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello beautiful worlds!");
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 3 - Main program which loads the DLL implementing AdapterBase*
**Program.cs**

```
namespace MyProgram {
    internal class Program {
        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            AdapterBase adapter = LoadAdapterFromPath("C:\\test\\Adapter");
            adapter.PrintHello();
        }

        public static AdapterBase LoadAdapterFromPath(string dir) {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.dll");
            AdapterBase moduleToBeLoaded = null;
            foreach (var file in files) {
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(file);
                foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes()) {
                    if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AdapterBase))) {
                        try {
                            moduleToBeLoaded =
                                assembly.CreateInstance(type.FullName, false, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null,
                                    null, null) as AdapterBase;
                        } catch (Exception ex) {

                        }
                        if (moduleToBeLoaded != null) {
                            return moduleToBeLoaded;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return moduleToBeLoaded;
        }
    }
}
```

So now the main program *MyProgram.cs* will try to load the DLL from path *C:\test\Adapter* and this works fine if I **ONLY** put the file *MyAdapter.dll* in that folder. However Solution 2 (*MyAdapter.cs*), will put both *MyAdapter.dll* and *AdapterBase.dll* in the output bin/ directory. Now if copy both those files to *c:\test\Adapter* the instance from the DLL does not get loaded since the comparison 
**if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AdapterBase))) {** fails in *MyProgram.cs*.

Since *MyProgram.cs* already has a reference to AdapterBase.dll there seems to be some conflict in an other DLL gets loaded from a different path which references the same DLL. The loaded DLL seems to first resolve its dependencies against DLLs in the same folder. I think this has to do with assembly contexts and some problem with the LoadFrom method but I do not know how to get C# to realise that it actually is the same DLL which it already has loaded.

A solution is of course only to copy the only needed DLL but my program would be much more robust if it could handle that the other shared DLL also was there. I mean they are actually the same. So any solutions how to do this more robust?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a type identity problem.  A .NET type's identity is not just the namespace and type name, it also includes the assembly it came from.  Your plugin has a dependency on the assembly that contains IAdapter, when LoadFrom() loads the plugin it is also going to need that assembly.  The CLR finds it in the LoadFrom context, in other words in the c:\test\adapter directory, normally highly desirable since that allows plugins to use their own DLL versions.

Just not in this case.  This went wrong because you plugin solution dutifully copied the dependencies.  Normally highly desirable, just not in this case.

You'll have to stop it from copying the IAdapter assembly:

- Open the plugin solution and use Build > Clean.
- Delete a remaining copy of the IAdapter assembly in the output directory with Explorer.
- Select the IAdapter assembly in the plugin solution's References node.  Set its `Copy Local` property to False.
- Use Build > Build and verify that the IAdapter assembly indeed does not get copied anymore.

`Copy Local` is the essence, the rest of the bullets are there just to make sure that an old copy doesn't cause problems.  Since the CLR can no longer find the IAdapter assembly the "easy way", it is forced to keep looking for it.  Now finding it in the Load context, in other words, the directory where the host executable is installed.  Already loaded, no need to load the one-and-only again.  Problem solved.

Comment: Thats a good answer although I am still not quite happy with the solution. There is no possibility in forcing LoadFrom to resolve references in MyPrograms folder first? Or just telling LoadFrom that this DLL is actually already loaded, i.e. assembly1::namespace::Type is actually the same as assembly2::namespace::Type?

Comment: You are asking for more DLL Hell, I can't realistically hand you that length of rope.  Only reasonable way is to put the assembly in the GAC, that's always safe and reliable.  Not a common SO recommendation, perhaps best to not over-react to a simple project configuration problem.

Comment: Okey I will just have to accept that this cant be done with Assembly.LoadFrom. However, I posted a solution that solved my problem, altough the solution is not really what the question is actually asking..

Comment: Hmm, Assembly.Load() scales rather poorly for plugins, you can't store them in separate directories anymore and have to stuff them all into a single one.  DLL Hell now strikes when one plugin overwrites the DLL of another, very hard to diagnose.  It is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem, although the path for the DLL can not be fully arbitrary. I was able to put the DLLs into, for example, *bin/MyCustomFolder* and load the DLL without getting the Type conflict problem.

The solution was to use the `Assembly.Load()` method which takes the full assembly name as argument. So first I find the name of the assembly by loadning all DLLs in the specified folder and the use `Assembly.GetTypes()` and checking if the Type is a subclass of `AdapterBase`. Then I use `Assembly.Load()` to actually load the assembly, which elegantly loads the DLL without any Type conflicts.

**Program.cs**

```
namespace MyProgram {
    internal class Program {
        private static void Main(string[] args) {

            string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
            UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
            string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
            string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
            string pathToLoad = Path.Combine(dir, "MyCustomFolder");
            AdapterBase adapter = LoadAdapterFromPath(pathToLoad);
            adapter.PrintHello();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Loads the adapter from path. LoadFile will be used to find the correct type and then Assembly.Load will be used to actually load
        /// and instantiate the class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dir"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static AdapterBase LoadAdapterFromPath(string dir) {
            string assemblyName = FindAssembyNameForAdapterImplementation(dir);
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
            Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
            Type adapterType = null;
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AdapterBase)))
                {
                    adapterType = type;
                    break;
                }
            }
            AdapterBase adapter;
            try {
                adapter = (AdapterBase)Activator.CreateInstance(adapterType);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                adapter = null;
            }
            return adapter;
        }

        public static string FindAssembyNameForAdapterImplementation(string dir) {
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.dll");
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(file);
                foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
                {
                    if (type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(AdapterBase)))
                    {
                        return assembly.FullName;
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** It is also important to add the extra probing path for `Assembly.Load()` to find the assembly in *bin/MyCustomFolder*. The probing path must be a subdir of the executing assembly, therefore it is not possible to have the DLL in a completely arbitrary location. Update your *App.config* as below:

**App.config**

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="MyCustomFolder"/>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

*Tip:* Actually I was having this problem for a Web application I had created. In that case you should update *Web.config* instead. Also in that case the probing path does not have the executing assembly as root but is actually the root of your web application. So in that case you can put you DLL folder *MyCustomFolder* directly in you web apps root folder, for example: *inetpub\wwwroot\mywebapp\MyCustomFolder* and then update Web.config as App.config above.